# Akka actor implementation: extension or injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, akka, subclass, actor

I am brand new to Akka (I'm using the Java lib v2.3.9), and am wondering what the tradeoff(s) is between two competing actor implementation strategies. On one hand I could implement my actors the *standard* way:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof ExecuteOrder66) {
            // Betray all Jedi, serve the Emperor!
        }
    }
}

class DarthVader extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof Feels) {
            // Betray the Emperor, save your son!
        }
    }
}

class Emperor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof Mace) {
            // Transform into your true self!
        }
    }
}
```

...instead of doing that, I could add a layer of abstraction via injection:

```
class StarWarsCharacter extends UntypedActor {
    @Inject // Injected behavior; implementation doesn't matter
    BehaviorHandler behaviorHadler

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        behaviorHandler.handle(message)
    }
}

interface BehaviorHandler {
    void handle(Object message)
}

class StormTrooperBehaviorHandler implements BehaviorHandler {
    @Override
    void handle(Object message) {
        // Betray all Jedi, serve the Emperor!
    }
}

class DarthVaderBehaviorHandler implements BehaviorHandler {
    @Override
    void handle(Object message) {
        // Betray the Emperor, save your son!
    }
}

class EmperorBehaviorHandler implements BehaviorHandler {
    @Override
    void handle(Object message) {
        // Transform into your true self!!
    }
}
```

Are there performance/classloading benefits to only having one type of actor and injecting it with different `BehavioHandler` implementations? Is there a reason why I would *not* want to do this and use the "standard" actor implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you just want to use your Actor as a way of dispatching messages to handlers, then the 2nd (non standard) way will be fine, and could give you some benefits in terms of code structure - e.g. the fact that `BehaviorHandler` is a single method interface would allow you to implement it with a lambda.

**However**, Actors are *not* simply method dispatchers. They provide a variety of methods that you will need as your system grows in complexity.

See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/untyped-actors.html#untypedactor-api

A typical, moderate sized Akka system will need references to `self`, `sender` and `context` which are defined on `UntypedActor`.

In short: if you don't use inheritance then you are giving up more than you realise.

Comment: Thanks @Tim (+1) - what about configuration & tuning? In addition to your arguments regarding the `UntypedActor` API, if it was possible to configure actors by type (pool sizes, etc.) I guess that would be another solid argument for the "standard" implementation...thoughts?